# Запросы MySQL

Tags: запрос, mysql

Имеются таблицы

`Order`- `idOrder`, `login`, `product`, `number`;

`Payment` - `idPayment`, `orderId`, `number` (оплаченное количество из заказа в табл. `Order`).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, запросы `SELECT`:

- получить строки (заказы) `Order` на которые нет ссылки в таблице оплат `Payment`;
- получить строки (заказы) `Order` на которые есть ссылки в таблице оплат `Payment`;
- получить строки (заказы) `Order` на которые есть ссылки в таблице оплат `Payment` при условии неравенства полей `number` в одной и второй таблицах, а также разность этих значений, т.е. `o.number-p.number;`

Comment: @rvm, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: @rvm, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: 1) делаю через 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM payment AS p WHERE p.orderId=o.idOrder) вроде Ok, но хотел свериться,
2) делаю через WHERE (p.orderId=o.idOrder), вроде тоже Ок,
3) делаю через WHERE (p.orderId=o.idOrder AND p.number<>o.number), получаю непонятное множество, поэтому интересует ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ вариант

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте про агрегирующие функции и конструкцию HAVING